# Anbox Stuck on Starting

Tags: android-emulator, anbox

**Anbox** seems to be stuck on starting. I tried to use the command `anbox session-manager` but it gives me the error:

> [ 2017-10-26 08:50:22] [Renderer.cpp:99@initialize] Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Adding it to the startup applications doesn't work either.

Below is the output of `anbox system-info`:

```
version: 3
snap-revision: 64
os:
  name: Ubuntu
  version: 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)
  snap-based: true
kernel:
  version: Linux version 4.13.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-02) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)) #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017
  binder: true
  ashmem: true
graphics:
  egl:
    vendor: n/a
    version: n/a
    extensions: []
  gles2:
    vendor: n/a
    vendor: n/a
    extensions: []
```

Comment: 1.Yes 2. Yes, I rebooted. 3. I clicked the anbox icon to start the anbox app manager. Anbox started working after I changed the graphics driver from Nvidia to Xorg drivers. I want to run Anbox with Nvidia drivers. Is there any solution ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To start Anbox type "anbox" in the Dash and click the Anbox icon to start the Anbox Application Manager.
2. Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers still don't work on Wayland and only work on Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10. In order to enter an X session from the GDM login screen select **Ubuntu on Xorg**. If you have installed the Nvidia graphics driver it should work if you do this. To prove that it is working you can also install *nvidia-settings*.